# Rig moves mesh but not activly with the rig, only when move is done

Tags: animation, rigging

My rig stopped moving my character's mesh actively. It works, just only after the move has been made. It's like the mesh refreshes after the rig is done moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delay Refresh was toggled on. Make sure this is off. When toggled on, the rig will move separately from the mesh until you release click. It will instantly update to the rig but will not move with it unless this is toggled off.  I carefully scrutinized my backup file till I found one difference.

[image: Delay Refresh]